# I want to use a local url as http url link

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm attaching a document with a local url link to a Twilio Fax but it is expecting an http url. How do I convert a local url to an http url?

Comment: The only way to serve a file over http is to have a web server hosting that document. Additionally, if the limitation here is actually that some Twilio server somewhere in the cloud will do the actual attaching then it needs to be able to reach this document. Since I have no experience with Twilio I don't know what the limitations are here. If this is the case, however, you need to expose the document to the internet in such a way that the Twilio server can reach it. But again, to answer your question (though it may not actually help you), you need to have a web server running.

Comment: If the Application have access to the file system, there is no need to expose it using a server, it can be reached using file:// URI format, even if the file is in a shared folder can be accessed this way.

Comment: I took a quick glance on the web pages for Twilio Programmable Fax and you send everything as a request to the Twilio server. As such, you need to expose the document on a web server facing the internet and provide a link to the document reachable from the outside. Basically, you cannot attach a document only available locally. Note that this does not in any way make the answers already left to your question wrong, you just asked the wrong question :)

Comment: Good point :) I still have doubts if is possible to add a file placed on a shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the format file://

Windows examples:

```
file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
```

Linux examples:

```
file://localhost/etc/fstab
file:///etc/fstab
```

You can find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: I doubt that would work. If Twilio actually expects a URL of the file (instead of expecting it into the POST payload), it would require a publicly accessible address. So `file://C:/..` or `file://localhost/...` wouldn't be recognized.

Comment: Depends, if the file is in a shared folder it must work. But this is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file:///` if you want to access a local file on the user's file system.

e.g. `file:///C:/Users/user/Pictures/test.jpg`